# Instantiating Objects in its own Class

Tags: java

This is my first question here. I am a comp. Eng. student and our teacher gave us some problems to work on.

He basically asked us to create 2 `classes`; one of which should contain 2 overloaded `constructors` and some methods regarding `data encapsulation`, and the other should be the `main class`. Our job is to "`control`" the first class from the main class using methods from that class. He also mentioned that we should pass values of some `primitive` and reference type variables between classes. I wrote some piece of code, but i get a **`StackOverflow Error`** during the class that has constructors in it is initializing. To my knowledge, you get  this error when you do a recursion, but I don't get where I am doing it.

Here's the constructor class I coded (sorry for my bad naming, but since its just homework  I didn't think on my names):

```
public class ConstructorClass {

    //Fields
    private String str;
    private int integer;


    //Constructors
    public ConstructorClass(String a)   {
        str= a;
    }

    public ConstructorClass(int a)  {
        integer= a;
    }

    //Objects
    public ConstructorClass obj1= new ConstructorClass("abc");
    public ConstructorClass obj2= new ConstructorClass(1);


    //Methods
    public int getInteger() {
        return this.integer;
    }

    public String getString() {

        return this.str;
    }

    public ConstructorClass getObj1() {
        ConstructorClass obj= new ConstructorClass("");
        obj.str= obj1.str;
        return obj;
    }

    public ConstructorClass getObj2() {

        return obj2; 
    }
}
```

Edit: This is the error I am getting:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError   at
>   ConstructorClass.(ConstructorClass.java:19)

Line 19 is :

```
public ConstructorClass obj1= new ConstructorClass("abc");
```

Comment: Could you share the main class file also

Answer (score 2):

You get this because you've basically got the following:

```
public class ConstructorClass {
    //Objects
    public ConstructorClass obj1= new ConstructorClass("abc");
    public ConstructorClass obj2= new ConstructorClass(1);
}
```

This is a hidden form of recursion.

It is roughly equivalent to writing

```
public class ConstructorClass {
    public ConstructorClass(int a)  {
        public ConstructorClass obj1= new ConstructorClass("abc");
        public ConstructorClass obj2= new ConstructorClass(1);
        ...
    }

    ...
}
```

i.e. invoking the constructor from every constructor.

Also see the [official java tutorial on initializing fields](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/initial.html) - although this is not explicitly mentioned there, what it says about "instance initializer blocks" also applies to using a final method to initialize an instance field, which is what you did here:

> The Java compiler copies initializer blocks into every constructor.

The details are specified in [JLS 14, Chapter 8.3.2. Field Initialization](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se14/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.3.2) :

> If the declarator is for an instance variable (that is, a field that is not static), then the following rules apply to its initializer:
>
> [...]
>
> At run time, the initializer is evaluated and the assignment performed each time an instance of the class is created (§12.5).

Comment: thank you, this answers my question.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you instantiate a `ConstructorClass`, you also instantiate its two members, `obj1` and `obj2`. These members are themselves `ConstructorClass`es, so they each have `obj1` and `obj2` members which also get instantiated, and so on, until you fail with a `StackOverflowError`.

I'm not sure why you have these two members (i.e., I can't see a requirement for them), but if you really need to have them, you should have them in some different context (e.g., as `static` members, as local variables in some method, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

Your getting stackoverflow error because of creating below two object at class level itself:

```
public ConstructorClass obj1= new ConstructorClass("abc");
public ConstructorClass obj2= new ConstructorClass(1);
```

Following code might work for you:

```
public class ConstructorClass {

    //Fields
    private String str;
    private int integer;
    //Constructors
    public ConstructorClass(String a)   {
        str= a;
    }

    public ConstructorClass(int a)  {
        integer= a;
    }


    //Methods
    public int getInteger() {
        return this.integer;
    }

    public String getString() {

        return this.str;
    }

    public ConstructorClass getObj1() {
        ConstructorClass obj= new ConstructorClass("");
        obj.str= new ConstructorClass("abc").str;
        return obj;
    }

    public ConstructorClass getObj2() {
        return new ConstructorClass(1); 
    }

} 

class ConstructorExample{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new ConstructorClass("");
    }
}
```

Note:

If want to achieve encapsulation in your class make sure you have getter and setter methods for variable `str` and `integer`

Answer (score 0):

Stackoverflow is coming as class is getting instantiated recursively partially due to these lines

```
     //Objects
      public ConstructorClass obj1= new ConstructorClass("abc");
      public ConstructorClass obj2= new ConstructorClass(1);
```

Remove above two lines issue will gone. You will get 1 compile issue which should be easy to solve.

What's happening internally is, Suppose from ur main class you tried to create object of this class using

```
    ConstructorClass cc = new ConstructorClass("string");
```

Now 1st constructor will be used. Then instance field will be created. Instance field creation also calls constructor. Constructor will again creat`enter code here`e instance field. And this loops keeps on going which causes issues.

U need to learn how classes get loaded and in what order it gets created.  If u tried to use instance block or static block it would add more complexity/learning for you.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the fixed code, with the following changes implemented:

1. Remove the cyclic calls from ConstructorClass 
   (An object's method trying to instantiate itself)
2. Introduce **setInteger()**  and **setString()** methods in **ConstructorClass** to set the values of its private data members.
3. Instantiate the **ConstructorClass** objects from **MainClass**
4. Call the **setInteger()**  and **setString()** methods of **ConstructorClass** from  **MainClass**

**Working code:**

```
// File name:  MainClass.java

class ConstructorClass {
    //Fields
    private String str;
    private int integer;

    //Constructors
    public ConstructorClass(String a)   {
        str = a;
    }

    public ConstructorClass(int a)  {
        integer = a;
    }


    //Methods
    public int getInteger() {
        return this.integer;
    }

    public String getString() {
        return this.str;
    }

    public void setInteger(int a) {
        integer = a;
    }

    public void setString(String a) {
        str = a;
    }

}

public class MainClass {

    //Objects
    ConstructorClass obj1;
    ConstructorClass obj2;

    public MainClass() {
        obj1 = new ConstructorClass("abc");
        obj2 = new ConstructorClass(1);
    }

    public ConstructorClass getObj1() {
        ConstructorClass obj = new ConstructorClass("");
        obj.setInteger(100);
        obj.setString("Hello! How are you doing?");
        return obj;
    }

    public ConstructorClass getObj2() {
        return obj2;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MainClass mc = new MainClass();
        System.out.println("obj1 - integer = " + mc.getObj1().getInteger());
        System.out.println("obj1 - string = " + mc.getObj1().getString());
        System.out.println("obj2 - integer = " + mc.getObj2().getInteger());
        System.out.println("obj2 - string = " + mc.getObj2().getString());
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
> javac MainClass.java

> java MainClass
obj1 - integer = 100
obj1 - string = Hello! How are you doing?
obj2 - integer = 1
obj2 - string = null
```